# Specify a custom git tag with sbt-release

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-release

Is it possible to specify a git scheme for git tag names with sbt-release?

The tag commit message and comment can be specified. Per the README:

`releaseTagComment    := s"Releasing ${(version in ThisBuild).value}",
releaseCommitMessage := s"Setting version to ${(version in ThisBuild).value}",`

But I've been unable to find a way to change the default for the actual tag text, which is set to s"v${releaseVersion}".

I'd like to specify the project name in the tag string, e.g., "myproject-v0.1.1"

To clarify, by the "tag string", I mean the string you see in e.g., `git tag -l`

We have multiple projects in the same git repository, and they have similar version numbers, so tags like "v0.1.0" are ambiguous.

Comment: The question is confusing, what exactly are you asking? What is this "actual tag text" you refer to?  Isn't this covered by `releaseTagComment` and `releaseCommitMessage`?

Comment: @marios I've added some clarifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's an sbt-release configuration value `releaseTagName` which you can modify to customize how release tag is generated.
This is working for me:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    .... other settings ....
    releaseTagName := s"version-${if (releaseUseGlobalVersion.value) (version in ThisBuild).value else version.value}",
    ....
    )
```

If everything else fails you can also customize release steps, and write your own tagRelease step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom tag based on your requirement. Here is the approach which I have followed.

**Steps**

1. Add the below-given content in `build.sbt` file. Here if the branch is `master` then I am using the `semantic versioning` like: `1.0.1` but if the branch name is other than `master` then I am using the custom tag(`branch-name + git-commitid + timestamp`).

```
import scala.sys.process.Process

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)

name := "your-project-name"
scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

val branch = Process("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD").lineStream.head
version := {
  branch match {
    case "master" => (version in ThisBuild).value
    case _ => {
      val commit = Process("git rev-parse HEAD").lineStream.head
      val time = Process("git log -1 --format=%ct").lineStream.head
      branch +"-"+ commit +"-"+ time
    }
  }
}
```

2. Create a `version.sbt` file in your project's root directory and add `version in ThisBuild := "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT"`.
3. Finally you can use [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) or any other plugins to release/publish the artifacts in the repository.